# Cannot build a docker image in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am new to jenkins, and I am trying to basically build an image from a Dockerfile and get a green light after the image is build.

I keep running into the issue:

> [nch-gettings-started_master-SHLPWPHFAAYXF7TNKZMDMDGWQ3SU5XIHKYETXMIETUSVZMON4MRA]
>   Running shell script
>
> - docker build -t my-image:latest .
>
> /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/nch-gettings-started_master-SHLPWPHFAAYXF7TNKZMDMDGWQ3SU5XIHKYETXMIETUSVZMON4MRA@tmp/durable-a1f989d1/script.sh:
>   line 2: docker: command not found
>
> script returned exit code 127

My pipeline as code is as follow:

```
node {
  stage('Clone repository') {
    checkout scm
  }

  stage('Build image') {
    def app = docker.build("my-image:my-tag")
  }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
pipeline {
  agent any


  stages {
    stage ('clonse repo') {
      steps {
        checkout scm
      }
    }

    stage('build image') {
      steps {
        docker.build("my-image:my-tag")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have already installed the docker pipeline plugin. and by the way jenkins is running in my localhost
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
line 2: docker: command not found
```

That is your issue. Depending on where the job is running, you need to make sure your slave image/VM/machine has docker installed.

If you have jobs running on your master, make sure `docker` is installed there.
If you have jobs running in Kubernetes, make sure your slave image has docker installed.

EDIT :

Just saw that you're running on localhost. Make sure you have docker installed there and its in your `$PATH`

Comment: the question is how to check if docker is installed ? isn't the plugin I installed responsible for that ? I am not running any kubernetes job. just a hello world application with build a docker image from a dockerfile

Comment: after doing an`echo $PATH`, i get: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'